# How to retrieve values from multidimentional array using where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I'm passing a variable

```
numbers = ["one", "two", ["three", "four"], "five"]
```

to a query in my model: `Modelname.where(number: numbers )` but I only get retrieved objects with number attr number value equal to: "one", "two", "five".

How to get the "three" and "four" object ?

Comment: This is how: `numbers = ["one","two","three","four","five"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***flatten***](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten)

```
numbers = ["one","two",["three","four"],"five"]

some_variable = numbers.flatten
=> ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

Modelname.where(number: some_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Modelname.where(number: numbers.flatten )`